# putting the keyboard to sleep untill a special character sequence is pressed

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-device-driver

i am using Fedora17 on  Dell Laptop .i want my keyboard will be locked untill a special character sequence is pressed(e.g   abcde  )..then it will behave normally...how can i implement that programmatically?

Comment: I think you do that better in the user space than in the kernel space. There is no need to do this in the kernel area.

Comment: yeah.its true..but can you give any idea how can it be implemented in kernel space?

Answer (score 0):

If you're alright with changing the kernel (not just a kernel module), I would look in `linux/drivers/tty/vt/`.  Warning, this is not fool proof and I'm not sure how it'll react to key remapping or other things.

The actual kernel keycode mapping is generated at compilation time using `defkeymap.map` (if memory serves).  However, this is called from `int getkeycode` so you can probably implement your functionality there.  Before `getkeycode` returns, you should be able to perform any extra actions you might want (such as disabling the keyboard).

If you need to use a kernel module, you might be able to insert your own keycode handler in place `getkeycode`, but I won't guarantee that.

Comment: But the keyboard map can be changed by initialization scripts using `loadkeys` and most non-AZERTY users do change that.

Comment: Hence this is not a complete solution.  But it's at least a way to start if this must be done in the kernel.